# error al concatenar javascript y php

Tags: php

tengo error en la funcion `sel_dr(x,y)`

el error es en el segundo parametro lo estoy mandando como entero pero necesito pasarlo como string

```
$datos .= "<li onclick='sel_dr($(this).text(),".$sel['referencia'].")' >".$sel['referencia']."</li>";
```

quiero convertir `$sel['referencia']` en string

esto es lo que se manda y me causa error

```
sel_dr($(this).text(),Doctor Gustavo Passos)
tiene que cambiar a esto:
sel_dr($(this).text(),'Doctor Gustavo Passos')
```

Comment: Hola, eso se resuelve simple, pon `$datos .= "<li onclick='sel_dr($(this).text(),".'"'.$sel['referencia'].'"'.")' >".$sel['referencia']."</li>";`. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que solo lo estás imprimiendo con PHP, necesitas envolverlo en comillas afuera del codigo de PHP, para asi, cuando se imprima este sea un string

```
$datos .= "<li onclick='sel_dr($(this).text(),".'"'.$sel['referencia'].'"'.")' >".$sel['referencia']."</li>";
```